# codeigniter/Pyro: making sure one of three fields is valid

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter

I have three phone fields (work_phone, home_phone and cell_phone). I would like to make sure that the user fills out at least one of them. This is my validation so far.

```
array(
    'field' => 'work_phone',
    'label' => 'lang:employee.work_phone',
    'rules' => 'max_length[10]|numeric|callback_check_phones[work_phone]'
    ),
array(
    'field' => 'home_phone',
    'label' => 'lang:employee.home_phone',
    'rules' => 'max_length[10]|numeric|callback_check_phones[home_phone]'
    ),
array(
    'field' => 'cell_phone',
    'label' => 'lang:employee.cell_phone',
    'rules' => 'max_length[10]|numeric|callback_check_phones[cell_phone]'
    ),

function check_phones($value,$name) {
    if((!isset($_POST[$name]))) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_phones', 
            'You must enter at least one phone number');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

The problem is that it makes ALL the phone fields required. If I try `if((!isset($_POST[work_phone])) ||(!isset($_POST[home_phone])) ){` no error is returned. 
What's the best way to check if one of the three fields is not null?

**EDIT**
I got this to work by using `empty()` instead of `isset()` and `&&` instead of `||` I know have

```
function check_phones($value){
    if((empty($_POST['work_phone'])) && (empty($_POST['home_phone'])) && (empty($_POST['cell_phone']))){
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_phones', 'You must enter at least one phone number');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

}
```

Which works but returns the error three times

Comment: Why are you not using the CI Input Class?

Comment: @Peter, I'm actually using PyroCMS and this is my first time using CI. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Codeigniter has a built in class that help's the overall usage and security of $_POST. You can read about it here...

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

Comment: Okay got it to work by only calling back the validation function on one of the phone elements. No need to call it three times.

Comment: @Peter, none of the answers answer the question the way I solved it. I also don't feel right about answering my own question the marking it the solution.

Comment: i have two phone number and this callback_ is not working properly what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use `empty()` instead of `isset()` see above.

Answer (score 1):

just change your !isset statements to isset:

```
if(isset($_POST['phone1') || isset($_POST['phone2']) || isset($_POST['phone3'])){
   //at least 1 is filled.
}else{
   //fail
}
```

Comment: would that be saying that if the field IS set to return false and show an error?

Comment: This is saying that if at least one of the fields is set, passing your validation requirement, edited for clarity

Comment: :) hope it helped :) speak up if you have any other questions

Comment: at this point it seems to be more of a CI problem with the way they handle validation. (see edit)

Answer (score 1):

how about using the CI input class... $this->input->post will return a false if its empty

```
if($this->input->post('work_phone') || $this->input->post('home_phone') || $this->input->post('cell_phone'))
    {
        echo "We have your phone!";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Please enter at least one!";
    }
```

**Update for CI's validation..**.

If they haven't filled in any phone field, you could just add validation for the first one. Like so...

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
    if($this->input->post('work_phone') || $this->input->post('home_phone') || $this->input->post('cell_phone'))
    {
        echo "At least one is in there";
    }
    else
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('work_phone', '1 Phone', 'required');
//      echo "Please enter at least one!";
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that this method works too or I use `empty()` instead of `isset` it works with `$_POST[work_phone]` I just show the same error 3 times.